# Get next and previous versions for a version id using paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the [paper_trail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) to version my Pages model.

I have a method called `version` which takes a `page_id` and `version_id`.

```
def version
  page = Page.where(id: params[:page_id]).first
  @version = page.versions.where(id: params[:version_id]).first
  @previous_version = @version.previous_version rescue nil
  @next_version = @version.next_version rescue nil
end
```

What I want to do is get the next and previous versions to pass them to my view. However I can only access the current version. `@previous_version` and `@next_version` are always `nil` even though I have next and previous versions. It seems it doesn't know what the methods `previous_version` and `next_version` are.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `@version.next` and `@version.previous` instead of `@version.next_version` and `@version.previous_version` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version object has [`next`](https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/gems/paper_trail/3.0.0.beta1/symbols/PaperTrail::Version/next) and [`previous`](https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/gems/paper_trail/3.0.0.beta1/symbols/PaperTrail::Version/previous) methods, whereas the versioned object (in your case it's `@page`) has methods `next_version` and `previous_version`.

So:

```
@page.previous_version
#=> returns previous version of @page object
```

whereas

```
@page.versions.previous
#=> returns a previous version object
```

Comment: @Cameron edited the answer with some more details :)